# Is it possible to link msproject with the TFS system?

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2010, tfs

I wonder if it is possible to create and manage tasks in microsoft project 2010 and commit the modifications to the TFS project's tasks?
It will be practical to raise the percentage of a task in MSProject and send this modification to the TFS server..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, I manage some tasks this way between TFS and MS Project.

In Project you need the Team toolbar showing, which allows you to "Choose Team Project" and connect to your TFS server. Once you've browsed to your project, choose "Get Work Items" and browse for your queries that can retrieve tasks / bugs / etc (I use Visual Studio 2010 to construct queries).

Once you have the list, you will probably want to modify the Project columns and fields to get everything in easy to reach places - I like to add 'Remaining Work' and '% Complete' for example. Go through, make all your changes, hit "Publish" and you're done.

Answer (score 6):

As Gary describes, with Team Explorer installed, you can review TFS Work Items directly using MS Project.

If you need more flexibility than that, also check out the [TFS Project Server Integration](https://web.archive.org/web/20150626103730/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2011/03/08/vs-tfs-2010-sp1-and-tfs-project-server-integration-feature-pack-have-released.aspx).  Among other things, this tool allows you to use detailed Tasks and other work items in TFS and track to a "rolled-up" project milestone in MS Project.