# How can I attach more text to a TFS task with MSProject?

Tags: ms-project, tfs

Following this [question](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/1201/is-it-possible-to-link-msproject-with-the-tfs-system/1215#1215) I have created a MSProject file to follow, create and manage tasks for teams in TFS system.

It works pretty good but it seems impossible to describe with precision the task, I mean in the TFS you can add a description to the task (Details/Description) but I don't see the possibility to edit/retrieve this field in MSProject.. Have anyone the tips to do that? Is it possible?

Thanks for response

Comment: bAN, did this work for you?

Comment: yes thank you, but so bad that the project manager (he is using MSProject) cannot add some remarks for each task throught his MSProject file..

Comment: Then definitely look at my second answer, it seems there is a way to do it within MSProject, it's just an out of the way view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this doesn't specifically answer the question you've asked, have you considered simply loading the task by ID via TFS's web interface (1)? I've used TFS since it was in initial betas and the availability of the web interface when they bought TeamPlain was a huge boost in their general accessibility by people other than the core development team (i.e. those who used Visual Studio all the time).

I've found it remarkably effective to create a search provider in my browser of choice so I can simply type the ID in the search box, or in Chrome type "tfs1234". This should save quite a bit of time. For Chrome, simply right click on the address bar and choose "Edit Search Engines..." and for other browsers I wrote a [short tutorial](http://ericwilleke.com/posts/finding-creative-commons-images-on-flickr/) a while back that should be very easy to extend to the TFS link.

(1) If you can't find it, I believe it's usually on http://yourtfsserver:8090

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Team Foundation Task Sheet View" to edit all of the fields that are synchronized between TFS And MSProject.

More information is available [on this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380701.aspx) under the section titled "View and Modify Team Foundation Task Fields."

Comment: Per my above answer, I do still believe you should explore the full suite of tooling available in TFS and use the different views as appropriate to your needs.